# Loading Custom activiti.cfg.xml

Tags: spring, activiti

I am learning activiti.
Where I created one java application in that I am using hibernate + Spring + activiti where we have `activiti.cfg.xml`.
I want to load only database details like datasource and hibernate properties programatically, other thing e.g asyncExecutorActivate, etc I want to do using `activiti.cfg.xml`.

e.g
Following need to set using Programatically

```spring
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="<set_Using_Program>" />
    <property name="url" value="<set_Using_Program>" />
    <property name="username" value="<set_Using_Program>" />
    <property name="password" value="<set_Using_Program>" />
</bean>
```

This Information set using activiti.cgf.xml

```
    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
</beans>
```

How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply inject your values from properties file and build your own engine based on them. such as data source. follow this [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/07/orchestrating-work-with-activiti-and-spring-integration)

You can also build extensions on them see [userguide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Suppose i need to inject values from Java Class then what need to do? please provide example.

Comment: then you can simply `@autowire` them as you might do in a spring application. please follow the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

for Spring Boot you can configure process engine like this code. activitiproperties is a custom class that I write to get mail server parameters.

```
@Autowired
private SpringProcessEngineConfiguration springprocessengineconfiguration;
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerHost(activitiproperties.getMailServerHost());
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerPort(activitiproperties.getMailServerPort());
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerUsername(activitiproperties.getMailServerUserName());
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerPassword(activitiproperties.getMailServerPassword());
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerDefaultFrom(activitiproperties.getMailServerDefaultFrom());
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerUseSSL(activitiproperties.isMailServerUseSsl());
springprocessengineconfiguration.setMailServerUseTLS(activitiproperties.isMailServerUseTls());
```